# I want to rotate 90 degree 2Dplot on matlab

Tags: matlab

So, I used

```
view(90,90).
```

But it was not enough: the axis is a problem.

Axis was changed -> x+-> x- and y+ -> y-

What should I do?? Axis is the problem...

Especially x^2/4+ y^2/9=1

and rotate it from the origin 90 degrees

Comment: Possible dupplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087855/rotating-a-plot-in-matlab

Comment: Please provide an actual minimal example that we can run - I'm sure that this is quite simple, but we have nothing to work with.

Comment: I edited my example : rotate    90 degree from the origin       x^2/4   +   y^2/9=1

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [camup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camup.html) command. You will probably want to do something like `camup([1 0 0])` or possibly `camup([0 0 1])`.

Note I have never use the command (can't test since I only have MATLAB at work) so I can't guarantee it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The axis x (resp. y) are by default number from right to left (resp. from top to bottom), for the functions `imagesc` or `image`. You can switch to the cartesian mode using `axis xy`. This will place the origin of you axes at the lower left corner.

Also you can use `rot90(M)` for matrix rotation.

Comment: Can you apply it to my example??

Comment: I think we can help you only if you provide a small real example. There is no MATLAB function that directly plots  x^2/4 + y^2/9=1.